# Camera Intent show blurred image preview after take a picture for some devices

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, blur

I'm having some issues in taking picture using camera intent. It's alright in my and some of my friend's devices, but somehow it shows a little bug in samsung devices(mostly). When i take the picture, the preview of captured image seems so blurry. i've searched about it all over the internet and i found no answer.

The only thing i dont understand is that my code is doing well in my device test and btw i'm using google code so i'm pretty sure that will be okay in all devices. Now i'm so confused and dont know exactly what to do.

Here's my code :

My intent method :

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.codelabs.refillmybottle.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

onActivityResult :

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            File imgFile = new  File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
            Log.d(TAG, "imgfile size : " + imgFile.length());
            if(imgFile.exists()){
                Uri bp = Uri.fromFile(imgFile);
                Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                Bitmap bitmap = decodeUri(bp,300);
                chipdata++;
                encodedeImageData[chipdata - 1] = getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(bitmap);
                checkChipData();
                checkData();
            }
}
```

decodeUri is a method to decode you Uri to bitmap and resize it.

I do really hope that anyone could answer my error cause my boss got angry on me and i'm so confused :D. Thanks.

Comment: Found a solution?